# How do I specify characters I want to exclude from characters allowed in VB textfield?

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, textfield

I was looking for a way to not allow the following characters in my textboxes "&" "<" and ">". I know the syntax for regex and specifying characters allowed : "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$"
But I am looking for the syntax to specify multiple characters not allowed in a textfield.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a "negative" character class by placing the characters you don't want in `[^...]` (note the `^`) like so:

```
"^[^&<>]+$"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much. (I will accept your answer in seven minutes when it lets me :) )